# Stop Jquery from replacing the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, field

I almost got what I want now. (Cobbled together from code all over the internet.)

But I need to know how to keep my query from being over written.

Example I have a text field. When a word on the dropdown is selected it puts the text in to the form field. If I select another word it replaces that word. What I want it to do is to be able to select as much as I want and no matter how many words I touch it'll keep those unless I go up and backspace or delete them out of the form field.

Here's my code.

http://pastebin.com/1wnAZMNM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to append the new text to the input control instead of replacing its contents, possibly inserting a space character in-between:

```
$(".myselect").change(function() {
    $(".textbox").val($(".textbox").val() + ' ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Is there a reason this worked. I'd like to know why this worked and nothing else seemed too. (You saved my sanity!)

Comment: Maybe you're confused because the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method *returns* the text box's value when called *without* parameters, but *sets* the text box's value when called *with* a parameter. In my example, I first called `.val()` to obtain the current value of the text box, then appended a space, then appended the selected value of the dropdown list, and finally *passed* the resulting string back to `.val()` to *update* the text box's value.

Comment: That was confusing. But everything works wonderfully now. I was going about it 100x wrong for almost 2 days, but I really have to thank you for all your help. I'll never underestimate js again. :) It saved my butt.

Comment: This will have odd results if you have more than one `.textbox`. You can use a callback to make it nicer: `$('.myselect').change(function(){var select = this; $('.textbox').val(function(i, oldVal) { return oldVal + select.value; }); });`